# Can I log PIC time when training for a tailwheel or high performance endorsement?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training, far-61, logging

If I hire a CFI to train me for the tailwheel endorsement (this question also applies to the high performance endorsement), can I log PIC time when flying the tailwheel aircraft, or do I have to log dual received?

This question is specifically about FAA rules related to training/logging time, but if there are different rules in different countries, feel free to answer about those too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes and Yes; As long as you are rated for the category, class, and type (if required) of the aircraft that you are receiving the training in you could log both PIC and dual received.

14 CFR 61.51(e)(i) covers the logging of PIC time (which is perfectly legal in the scenario that you describe if you are rated in the aircraft):

> [§61.51   Pilot logbooks.](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr;sid=8ba6845324e8b8199b52458202355632;rgn=div8;view=text;node=14:2.0.1.1.2.1.1.31;idno=14;cc=ecfr)
>
> ...
>
> (e) Logging pilot-in-command flight time. (1) A sport, recreational,
>   private, commercial, or airline transport pilot may log pilot in
>   command flight time for flights-
>
> (i) When the pilot is the sole manipulator of the controls of an
>   aircraft for which the pilot is rated, or has sport pilot privileges
>   for that category and class of aircraft, if the aircraft class rating
>   is appropriate;

Training time is logged per 14 CFR 61.51(h) and you can log that too:

> (h) Logging training time. (1) A person may log training time when
>   that person receives training from an authorized instructor in an
>   aircraft, flight simulator, or flight training device.

---

That being said, you may **not** act as the actual PIC however:

> [§61.31   Type rating requirements, additional training, and
>   authorization requirements.](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=b87c39b886c45df379486076a7d0d057&node=14:2.0.1.1.2.1.1.21&rgn=div8)
>
> ...
>
> (i) Additional training required for operating tailwheel airplanes.
>   (1) Except as provided in paragraph (i)(2) of this section, no person
>   may act as pilot in command of a tailwheel airplane unless that person
>   has received and logged flight training from an authorized instructor
>   in a tailwheel airplane and received an endorsement in the person's
>   logbook from an authorized instructor who found the person proficient
>   in the operation of a tailwheel airplane. The flight training must
>   include at least the following maneuvers and procedures:
>
> ...

---

Notice that the regulations governing **acting** as PIC are different than those governing **logging** of PIC time.  This was done intentionally because there were so many pilots that were hired as SIC's at airlines with little to no PIC time and flew for years. When it was time for them to upgrade they didn't have enough PIC time even though they had lots of experience and could easily upgrade safely.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes, you can still log PIC time** *if you are appropriately rated for that aircraft*, aside from the endorsement.

For example, if you are a Private Pilot, Airplane Single-Engine Land working on an endorsement in a Piper J-3 Cub, you would be able to log PIC time during your tailwheel training because the Cub is a single-engine land airplane.

The same goes for a MEL pilot adding tailwheel in a Twin Beech, which is an MEL airplane.

If you held *only an Airplane Single-Engine Sea* certificate, you could not log PIC time until you added on an ASEL rating.

[14 CFR 61.51](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr;sid=8ba6845324e8b8199b52458202355632;rgn=div8;view=text;node=14:2.0.1.1.2.1.1.31;idno=14;cc=ecfr)

> (e) Logging pilot-in-command flight time.
>
> > (1) A sport, recreational, private, commercial, or airline transport pilot may log pilot in command flight time for flights-
> >
> > > (i) When the pilot is the sole manipulator of the controls of an aircraft for which the pilot is rated, or has sport pilot privileges for that category and class of aircraft, if the aircraft class rating is appropriate;