# Can I log my military training time as PIC, if I have a PPL?

Tags: faa-regulations, military, usa, logging

It's my understanding that instrument and commercial training time can be logged as PIC, after you have a PPL.  I received my PPL in a standard C-172.

I was about to go through and log all my military training time (in the T-6 and T-38) this weekend, and was wondering if I can log all that as PIC?

[This questions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2297/can-i-log-pic-time-when-training-for-a-tailwheel-or-high-performance-endorsement) specifies that you must be be rated in the category and type to do so.  I'm not really sure what that means.  Of course I don't have any FAA ratings other than my PPL in the 172.

So, can I log my T-6 and T-38 time as PIC for my civilian records?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For FAA purposes you can log PIC time in the T6 because you hold a license in the airplane, single engine, land category and class.  However, the USAF might not see it that way.

Since you do not have an FAA license for the category and class multi engine land, you can only log PIC time for your solo flights in the T38.

Comment: Thanks!  I only had like 10 PIC hours before pilot training, so I'll take 85 more from the T6.  Kind of stupid about the dual engine.  It's really not cosmic... bummer it's considered so different for logging purposes.  And yeah, yte Air Force doesn't care about my FAA ratings at all.  So the even the T-6 time doesn't count for much as far as they're concerned.

Comment: You’re welcome.  I kinda had the reverse situation, got ATP Multi first, and only recently added commercial SEL.  You should be able to add commercial SEL and Multi on the basis of your military training.  Checkout Shepard air for the gouge if you haven’t already.